# How to search git logs for change to a given file?

Tags: git

How can one search all commits to find the ones when changes were made to file ABC?

Assume, /path/to/file is not known.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [git-blame](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) command:

```
git blame /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `git log -- <filename>`

The following will give a log of all commits that changed ABC in the current dir:

```
git log -- ABC
```

If it's in a subdirectory and you're not sure where, use the following instead:

```
git log -- */ABC
```

It works even if ABC lies several subdirectories deep.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the commit name and hash:

```
git log --pretty=oneline -- /path/to/file
```